# Why does using "return" in Rails.cache.fetch block fail to cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Why does using return in `Rails.cache.fetch` cause a cache miss?

```
# doesn't catch
Rails.cache.fetch("key", expires_in: 12.hours) do
 puts "CACHE MISS" 
 return "HI"
end

# caches
Rails.cache.fetch("key", expires_in: 12.hours) do 
 puts "CACHE MISS"
 "HI"
end
```

Comment: Because its not C# bro :) In short: `return` exits immediately from `fetch` method without processing(caching) of block yielding results. Google `ruby block return` for details.

Answer (score 3):

To provide an explanation for this, we first need to understand how yield works:

- The yield keyword allows passing a set of additional instructions during a method invocation. Meaning, that a method can accept a block (besides the regular arguments) and execute that block from inside the method by using the yield keyword.
- Another thing we need to know is that when executing a yield block, if calling return in it, it returns the whole method and not just the block.
- See further information on `yield` [here](https://medium.com/rubycademy/the-yield-keyword-603a850b8921).

The `Rails.cache.fetch` method is implemented by accepting a block and executing it using the `yield` keyword (with some additional logic).
Hence, When returning from inside the block that is sent to `Rails.cache.fetch`, the whole method is returned without first processing (caching) the block yielding results, and the caching fails.